How to move cousin html elements by css only
I am making a simple calendar that has days as columns, and multiple events each day. This is simple. However, some events go over two days and I wonder if it is possible to display this with css only. The content will of course be dynamic, so can't hardcode anything.
Here is the concept I'm trying to achieve:

Requirements

The events shouldn't overlap (example: the event on Monday that goes into Tuesday should occupy place on Tuesday)
Events should be possible to drag from one day to another. Drag&drop will be solved with Javascript, but in order to solve it I need to know on which day the events are dropped onto. This affects how html is built, I think.

The html will look something like this:
<div class="week">
  <div class="day-column" data-date="2024-06-03">
    <div class="event">Event 1</div>
    <div class="event overnight">Event 2</div>
    <div class="event">Event 3</div>
    <div class="event">Event 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day-column" data-date="2024-06-04">
    <div class="event">Event 1</div>
    <div class="event">Event 2</div>
    <div class="event overnight">Event 3</div>
    <div class="event">Event 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day-column" data-date="2024-06-05">
    <div class="event">Event 1</div>
    <div class="event">Event 2</div>
    <div class="event">Event 3</div>
    <div class="event">Event 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day-column" data-date="2024-06-06">
    <div class="event">Event 1</div>
    <div class="event">Event 2</div>
    <div class="event">Event 3</div>
    <div class="event overnight">Event 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day-column" data-date="2024-06-07">
    <div class="event">Event 1</div>
    <div class="event">Event 2</div>
    <div class="event">Event 3</div>
    <div class="event">Event 4</div>
  </div>
</div>

Week will be a flex container, the days its children, with the events block elements.
Is this even possible to make with html and css only? Or am I doomed to make something super complicated setup where I have to make ghost objects with javascript, where events from previous day overlap only to push down overlapped events today?
Any ideas?

CSS-Grid can do this (no separate column wrappers required) but each event would need to have specified locations (Day, hour start and hour end etc).

HTML Table may solve your problem.

@Paulie_D I didn't specify it above, but the events will be draggable, so I thought I needed the column wrappers to know where they are dropped.

Flexbox isn't an option here as it can't span across wrappers.

You might be able to keep the column wrappers by using subgrid but it will complicate the location placing

I have updated the post to detail the drag & drop requirement. Lesson learned, always add all relevant requirements!

There appears to be no "time" component involved here (meaning, you would not need to leave any event slot "empty", and then have another event later on that same day still - correct?) - so I'm wondering, if a flexbox row direction container with wrapping might not be an option? You'd simply insert events that are one day, two days, ... days "wide" then. But of course that would need moving event elements around in the DOM then, when you re-arrange them via drag&drop.

@CBroe that is correct, there is no time to think about. The events are just stacked underneath each other.

I see what you mean regarding flexbox row direction, and I have thought about it myself. But ended up scrapping it, because of three things really. One - how to keep track of which day I drop on, two - possible massive changes when moving events, and three - I think I was thinking if some days had many events and other none and display issues around that.

Three: Yes, you would have to insert "empty" elements as placeholders - for example, the fifth slot on your Monday above, would need one such placeholder, so that the following event moves over into the Tuesday "column." One: You could go by the x/y coordinates the user drags an element to, relative to the container - even when making this responsive, you can query the width of one column, and how high one event actually is, via JS - so you should be able to "do the math", to determine what the new day & slot for the dragged event is, when it finally gets dropped.

Part Two would be the most complex aspect here, true. But the flexbox approach is still the easiest I see here, to get the multiple day events implemented in the first place. (I'm not too up-to-date with grid, I have to admit, so I can't tell how complex Paulie_d's subgrid approach would turn out, in comparison.) Before flexbox or grid, I would probably have gone with absolute positioning - but that will increase the effort necessary to re-arrange all other elements by a lot.

Here's a way of laying things  out as required while maintaining the HTML structure.
It uses CSS grid with the display: contents option on the days so their contents are included.
If an element is moved to a different day for example in the HTML it will pick up the correct CSS as the selectors are related to child positions.
Note: the CSS is spelled out here to make things clear. No doubt there are ways of shortening it e.g. with CSS variable (and getting rid of the importants??)


<style>
  .week {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
    width: 90vw;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
  }
  
  .day-column {
    display: contents;
  }
  
  .day-column:nth-child(1) .event {
    grid-column: 1 / span 1!important;
  }
  
  .day-column:nth-child(1) .event.overnight {
    grid-column: 1 / span 2!important;
  }
  
  .day-column:nth-child(2) .event {
    grid-column: 2 / span 1!important;
  }
  
  .day-column:nth-child(2) .event.overnight {
    grid-column: 2 / span 2!important;
  }
  
  .day-column:nth-child(3) .event {
    grid-column: 3 / span 1!important;
  }
  
  .day-column:nth-child(3) .event.overnight {
    grid-column: 3 / span 2!important;
  }
  
  .day-column:nth-child(4) .event {
    grid-column: 4 / span 1!important;
  }
  
  .day-column:nth-child(4) .event.overnight {
    grid-column: 4 / span 2!important;
  }
  
  .day-column:nth-child(5) .event {
    grid-column: 5 / span 1!important;
  }
  
  .day-column:nth-child(5) .event.overnight {
    grid-column: 5 / span 2!important;
  }
  
  .event.overnight {
    background-color: pink;
  }
  
  .event {
    background-color: cyan;
  }
</style>
<div class="week">
  <div class="day-column">
    <div class="event">Event 1.1</div>
    <div class="event overnight">Event 1.2</div>
    <div class="event">Event 1.3</div>
    <div class="event">Event 1.4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day-column">
    <div class="event">Event 2.1</div>
    <div class="event">Event 2.2</div>
    <div class="event overnight">Event 2.3</div>
    <div class="event">Event 2.4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day-column">
    <div class="event">Event 3.1</div>
    <div class="event">Event 3.2</div>
    <div class="event">Event 3.3</div>
    <div class="event">Event 3.4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day-column">
    <div class="event">Event 4.1</div>
    <div class="event">Event 4.2</div>
    <div class="event">Event 4.3</div>
    <div class="event overnight">Event 4.4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="day-column">
    <div class="event">Event 5.1</div>
    <div class="event">Event 5.2</div>
    <div class="event">Event 5.3</div>
    <div class="event">Event 5.4</div>
  </div>
</div>




Good answer! A little improvement:    Set  on the events only the start .day-column:nth-child(1) .event {  grid-column-start: 1;} and then only 1 style for .overnight { grid-column-end: span 2;}

@vals thanks - I'll wait in the hopes of more improvements and then edit the CSS to make it less clunky.

This looks very promising! I'll test it out immediately. Good job!

Just had a thought, do you stop people dragging an overnight event to Friday? If not what do you want to happen to that event?

Good question, @AHaworth! I won't stop them doing it, so I guess its a matter of how to show the event "continues" into the next day. Need to ponder about that one.
